# The method permissions() is undefined for the type Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am new in Google Drive Integration Application. I am trying to integrate this code in [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) android google drive sample.

But I am getting this error:

```
The method permissions() is undefined for the type Drive
```

Code:

```
  try {
         return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
      } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      }
```

I am importing `import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive`; Instead of `import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive`;
Taken From..Complete Code  [Google drive share api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#examples)..

Edited One:

When i try to import

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission;
```

I am facing another issue near packagename

Issue:

```
The type com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Could Somebody help me out. Thanks

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear: There's no method called `permissions()` for the type `Drive`, which I presume `service` is. Are you sure you're using the right method?

Comment: Yes,But when i called this import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive; I am facing another issue:( Check the updated Question.

Comment: On SO you can't post a question, then edit it to be a different question. The answer to your original question is 'you used the wrong import'. Now ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: But is there any method to solve the above issue for sharing file